# Next JS route is not resolving in production build

Tags: express, routes, next.js, server-side-rendering, next-router

I have a following route pattern in the custom server of NextJs project. Everything works fine in the development. But in production build the route is not recognised and goes to 404 page.

Routes

```
{ name: 'business-with-key', pattern: '/:keyword-in-:location', page: 'packages/index' },
```

In the development I can get both the params with this code.

packages/index.tsx

```
export const getServerSideProps: any = async (ctx: NextPageContext) => {
  const { query, req } = ctx;

  const { keyword, location } = query;
```

But when I build the project in docker and run it, the route `http://localhost:3000/photo-in-london` reaches 404 when deep linked. Works fine with SPA navigation.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Can you show the server code you have that supposedly handles that routing?

Comment: The server side is handled and this is the route relevant to that,
`{ name: 'business-with-key', pattern: '/:keyword-in-:location', page: 'packages/index' }` and it works in dev

Comment: @sinthu225 Did you find a solution ? I've similar problem. Thank you !

Comment: Please share if you found a solution to this problem